# What does it mean when I assign {} to an already exsiting object?

Tags: c++, c++11, grammar

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<priority_queue<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back({});//compiles
    vec.push_back({1});//don't work 
    vec[0] = {};//compiles
    vec[0] = {1};//don't work 
    return 0;
}
```

**priority_queue doesn't have a initializer list constructor .**

But I can still assign a {} to it .

I think it means that I just constructed an empty priority_queue using the default constructor,and assigned it to the already exsiting priority_queue object .

But shouldn't that be something like this ?

```
vec[0] = priority_queue<int>{};//compiles
vec[0] = priority_queue<int>();//compiles
```

What does this acctuly mean ?And why does it work ?
I just omitted the priority_queue part .

```
vec[0] = {};//compiles
vec[0] = ();//don't work
```

That dosen't mean I can reinitialize my queue object at any time ,dose it ?

```
priority_queue<int> que{};
que = {};//compiles
que{};//don't work
```

Is {} here something like nullptr ?

{} is an empty object for everything like nullptr is an empty pointer for every kind of pointers ?

```
priority_queue<int>* p{};
p = nullptr;
p = {};// still works
```

Comment: Old C++ had lots of different ways to initialize something. So we added a new, *uniform initialization*, so now you have all the old ways plus another, new way.

Comment: This is actually ill-formed since the default constructor of `priority_queue` happens to be `explicit`. Probably a defect in the standard, though.

Comment: And the new way has even more corner cases than the old way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment operator (including compound assignment) is given special treatment in C++11, since it is included into the list of contexts where list-initialization is allowed to occur. Because of that special treatment a plain `{ ... }` initializer is allowed on the right-hand side of assignment operator, as in your

```
vec[0] = {};
```

And, according to the specification of assignment operator, it is interpreted as

```
vec[0].operator =({});
```

In this case `{}` is used as an initializer for an argument in function call. Since the object being initialized is not an aggregate, the contents of `{}` is interpreted as argument list for regular constructors. Since the list is empty it results in default constructor being selected.

This special treatment does not extend to other operators

```
struct S
{
  S(int, int, int) {}
  S &operator +=(const S& rhs) { return *this; }
  S operator +(const S& rhs) const { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
  S s(1, 2, 3);
  s = { 4, 5, 6 };  // OK - special treatment for `=`
  s += { 4, 5, 6 }; // OK - special treatment for `+=`
  s + { 4, 5, 6 };  // Error - no special treatment for `+`
  s + S{ 4, 5, 6 }; // OK, constructing the object explicitly works
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning a pitfall here: if there are multiple overloads of `operator=` then overload resolution might give a surprising result (conversion of `{}` to builtin type is preferred to conversion to class-type, so the copy-assignment operator may not be selected).

Comment: @M.M: Yes, the fact that initializers like `{ 1 }` prefer the built-in type might appear quite natural, but the fact that `{}` also prefers the built-in type might be seen as surprising by many people.

Answer (score 2):

Braces (`{}`) are used generically for initialisation of objects, not just initialiser lists. So a class with no initialiser list can still use braces to initialize an object e.g.

```
class A { 
    public: 
    A(int i);
}

A a{5}; // Invokes A's constructor
```

It can also be used for [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (e.g. initialization of a structs data members.) In your case, it is invoking the default contructor of `priority_queue`.